# audio on hover over various short texts (webpage)

Tags: javascript

for the educational part of my (foreign languages) webpages I'd like to let the visitor hover over a number of sentences and listen to the corresponding prerecorded audio.
I've got a short working script for that, but don't want to repeat the code every time on the page.
Is there a way to make a playlist or array of text and audio that will work?
(I'm ignorant of javascript, just start experimenting a bit).
Thanks!

This works fine, but there must be a better way than writing the script again & again...

```
<audio id="audio01"  preload="auto" src="#1.mp3"></audio>
   <audio id="audio02"  preload="auto" src="#2.mp3"></audio>
   <p id="a01" style="background-color:red;">Ὦ δώματ᾽ Ἀδμήτει᾽, ἐν οἷς ἔτλην ἐγὼ</p>
   <p id="a02" style="background-color:red;">θῆσσαν τράπεζαν αἰνέσαι θεός περ ὤν.</p>
      
   <script>
   var a01 = document.getElementById("a01");
   a01.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {   
       var audio01 = document.getElementById("audio01");
       audio01.play();
   }, false);
   
   a01.addEventListener("mouseout", function( event ) {   
          var audio = document.getElementById("audio01");
          audio.currentTime = 0;
          audio.pause();
      }, false);
      
var a02 = document.getElementById("a02");
        a02.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {   
            var audio02 = document.getElementById("audio02");
            audio02.play();
    }, false);
        
a02.addEventListener("mouseout", function( event ) {   
               var audio02 = document.getElementById("audio02");
               audio02.currentTime = 0;
               audio02.pause();
       }, false);
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some class on your `p` to select them with `querySelectorAll` and some data to select the good audio then apply a loop:

```js
   <audio id="audio01"  preload="auto" src="#1.mp3"></audio>
   <audio id="audio02"  preload="auto" src="#2.mp3"></audio>
   <p id="a01" style="background-color:red;" class="audio-over" data-linked="#audio01">Ὦ δώματ᾽ Ἀδμήτει᾽, ἐν οἷς ἔτλην ἐγὼ</p>
   <p id="a02" style="background-color:red;" class="audio-over" data-linked="#audio02">θῆσσαν τράπεζαν αἰνέσαι θεός περ ὤν.</p>
      
   <script>

   var lists = document.querySelectorAll('.audio-over');

   list.forEach( function(el) {
      el.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
         var target = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-linked');
         var audio = document.querySelector(target);
         audio.play();
      }, false);
   
      el.addEventListener("mouseout", function( event ) {   
          var target = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-linked');
          var audio = document.querySelector(target);
          audio.currentTime = 0;
          audio.pause();
      }, false);
   }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

index.html:

```html
...

<audio id="audio01"  preload="auto" src="#1.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="audio02"  preload="auto" src="#2.mp3"></audio>
<p id="a01" style="background-color:red;">Ὦ δώματ᾽ Ἀδμήτει᾽, ἐν οἷς ἔτλην ἐγὼ</p>
<p id="a02" style="background-color:red;">θῆσσαν τράπεζαν αἰνέσαι θεός περ ὤν.</p>
<script src="script.js"></script>

...
```

script.js:

```js
var elements = [
  [ "a01", "audio01" ],
  [ "a02", "audio02" ]
];

function setHandlers() {
  for (var i in elements) {
    var elementID = elements[i][0];
    var audioID = elements[i][1];
    var element = document.getElementByID(elementID);
    element.addEventListener("mouseover", function ( event ) {
      var audio = document.getElementById(audioID);
      audio.currentTime = 0;
      audio.play();
    }, false);
    element.addEventListener("mouseout", function( event ) {   
      var audio = document.getElementById(audioID);
      audio.currentTime = 0;
      audio.pause();
    }, false);
  }
}
```

This should allow you to add elements dynamically through the `elements` array, and then just call the `setHandlers()` function to set them up.

It's also helpful sometimes to have your JS in a separate file.